# What does this line mean in firebug? Blue writing on right hand side

Tags: http, firebug, fiddler, mvc-mini-profiler

I have firebug installed and I can see on one of my 'Net' requests that there is a bit of 'blue' writing on the right hand side..... Im wondering what this is?

[image]

Im using mini-profiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blue links like these point to a line of relevant source code. You'll find them in various parts of Firebug.

For instance, similar links appear next to console log messages.

[image: Firebug console message]

Clicking on such a link will show the line of JavaScript where *console.log()* was called.

Similarly, under the HTML *Style* sub-pane there are links to the relevant rules definitions in CSS files.

[image: CSS links]

In your case, that blue link points to the line of JavaScript code on which an XMLHttpRequest was sent. Clicking on that link will display the line in question under the *Script* tab.

[image: XHR link]

Though it seems that request was initiated from somewhere deep inside a minified copy of the jQuery library. Looking at that code won't be much help.

To understand what's going on you can click on the left margin of the request under the *Net* tab to set up a break point.

[image: break point under the Net tab]

And on the next request of this kind, look at the stack trace to see which part of your code caused that request to happen.

[image: stack trace]

Comment: I want to add that these source links can not just be found inside XMLHttpRequest logs but also in other logs inside the Console panel as well as in different other panels throughout Firebug like e.g. the Style side panel. See also http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel#Click_functionality.